# Monodroid sliding menu animation

Tags: android, optimization, xamarin.android, slidingmenu

I've managed to successfully add this *java* sliding menu library in my monodroid project.

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Everything works fine, but I feel that the sliding animation is somewhat "fragmented" at times.

I see that the latest version of the library uses 'LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE' when sliding the menu

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/lib/SlidingMenu.java#L988

but the sliding animation in a Monodroid application isn't as smooth as the one from the Java native application.

I know this is kind of a weird question, but any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue with java.

Check out this issue;
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/262#ref-commit-da9db11

I applied the fix of changing;

```
boolean layer = percentOpen > 0.0f && percentOpen < 1.0f;
```

To

```
boolean layer = percentOpen >= 0.0f && percentOpen <= 1.0f;
```

in SlidingMenu.java

This worked for me, except the very first slide still has a stutter, after that it's very smooth.

Comment: Tried you're advice. Works much better now. Thank you

Comment: super thanx,+1 for answer